# How to make the grid view table multiple row in one cells using VB.NET Webforms

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net web forms. I want to show the grid view like the image below. One grid view table that can contains all data and can separate different models with different colors like the image below. Besides that, I also want to show my Location in multiple rows in one cell. Does any one know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution is using nested gridview in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

1. If u simply need to show data as grid like above then go with HTML table which u create dynamically and show data in that table.
2. U can use nested grid view to show data and change that color in item data bind and based on model.
3. when select query u can group the location or u can add "/" or "or" in multiple location by code and bind in data table and then load in grid.